# What does it mean when a topology has a non-trivial countable base?

Tags: general-topology

I recently found that the standard topology has a countable base by utilizing the density of the rationals. Are there topologies that cannot have a countable base? If so, what makes them so different that they cannot have a countable base?

Comment: As there is a phrase *second countable* for topological spaces with a countable basis, one would guess that some spaces are not second countable.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of spaces without countable bases are
the ordinals $\omega_n$ for nonzero n,
uncountable discrete spaces.

2nd countable (has countable base) compact spaces have the property that every sequence has a convergent subsequence.